# Excel - Regular Expression replacement with dictionary value

Tags: vba, excel

We are trying to automatically translate certain part of a string in each Excel cell automatically based on an VBA dictionary.

Original String examples:

```
1.Outer Fabric:2% EA, 44% WO, 54% PES; Lining:4% EA, 96% RY
Outside:2% EA, 98% WO
1.Outer Fabric:27% PA, 73% WV; 2.Lining:100% CO; 2.Outer Fabric:100% AOS
```

Regular expression is defined as:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(\d{1,3}\%\s+)(\w+)"
```

The dictionary is constructed from another excel spreasheet. The example key/value pairs are:

```
EA: Leather
WO: Cloth
PES: Polyester
RY: Other
...
```

But I cannot find a way to use those dictionary keys to replace the original string. Line 12 below is what I tested, but it cannot find the dictionary value...

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(\d{1,3}\%\s+)(\w+)"
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A50")
With regex
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "$1" & IIf(Dict.Exists("$2"), Dict("$2"), "$2")

For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value
        cell.Value = regex.replace(strInput, strReplace)
    End If
Next
```

Any guidance to get this problem resolved is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot replace all of the dictionary keys in one shot: you'd need to replace each one in turn.  Use the pattern to get a Matches collection, then loop over that looking at the SubMatches for each one, running the replace as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need regex for this. When I translate I usually just use brute force with replace.

```
str = Replace ( str, "EA", "Leather")
str = Replace ( str, "WO", "Cloth")
str = Replace ( str, "PES", "Polyester")
```

Etc.
And once all replace has been done you know it has translated the abreviations that excist.
If `WO` is not in the string then the replace will fail and just continue with the next.

Comment: The problem with using replace for this scenario would not work.  If the string contains "25% EA, 35% EA, 40%EA", and I want to replace EA with LEA,  then the final string will have LLLEA

Comment: In addition, the string to be replaced could be thousands of lines, to do this for every entry is tedious.

Comment: LEA was not part of the scope. It's very important when you write a question that you don't "etc." when there is something that is important. But if you replace " EA" then you need a space first which will solve your problem. Tedious, yes. But that is what translations are. I have not seen any secure method that is not tedious. YMMV.

Comment: How does "EA" become "LLEA"? Was not EA supposed to be Leather? Then it's impossible to become LLEA?

Comment: I agree with this answer. A regex is useful if you can replace a pattern with a fixed string, but since you have pairs of Find/Replace strings then you might as well just do a bunch of Find/Replaces. I am also confused about how EA becomes LLLEA, so am maybe missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic outline:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim regEx As Object, dict As Object
    Dim matches, m
    Dim c As Range
    Dim s As String, mat As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.Add "EA", "Leather"
    dict.Add "WO", "Cloth"
    dict.Add "PES", "Polyester"
    dict.Add "RY", "Leather"

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regEx.Pattern = "(\d{1,3}\%\s+)(\w+)"
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.MultiLine = True

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
        s = c.Value
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(s)
        If Not matches Is Nothing Then
            'loop over each of the match objects
            For Each m In matches
                mat = m.submatches(1) '<<second submatch=material code
                If dict.Exists(mat) Then
                    s = Replace(s, m, Replace(m, mat, dict(mat)))
                End If
            Next m
        End If
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = s
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This works really well. Thank you very much, @tim-williams